# PHP accessing child's and grandchild's static properties from parent

Tags: php, static, parent, self

Given the following class hierarchy of in general unknown depth:

```
class P
{
    protected static $var = 'foo';

    public function dostuff()
    {
        print self::$var;
    }

}

class Child extends P
{
    protected static $var = 'bar';

    public function dostuff()
    {
        parent::dostuff();
        print self::$var;
    }
}

class GrandChild extends Child
{
    protected static $var = 'baz';

    public function dostuff()
    {
        parent::dostuff();
        print self::$var;
    }
}

$c = new GrandChild;
$c->dostuff(); //prints "foobarbaz"
```

Can I somehow get rid of the redefinitions of *dostuff()* while maintaining functionality?

Comment: What you mean of getting rid of the redefinition ? What is the expected output ?

Comment: The output shall not change at all. I want to avoid re-defining a dostuff() method in every child class, thus duplicating code.

Comment: But the output you want would be "baz" or "foo" when you print ?

Comment: Ah okay I get you saw the comment, let me think..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it

```
class P
{
    protected static $var = 'foo';

    public function dostuff()
    {
        $hierarchy = $this->getHierarchy();
        foreach($hierarchy as $class)
        {
            echo $class::$var;
        }
    }

    public function getHierarchy()
    {
        $hierarchy = array();
        $class = get_called_class();
        do {
            $hierarchy[] = $class;
        } while (($class = get_parent_class($class)) !== false);
        return array_reverse($hierarchy);
    }

}

class Child extends P
{
    protected static $var = 'bar';
}

class GrandChild extends Child
{
    protected static $var = 'baz';  
}

$c = new GrandChild;
$c->dostuff();
```

Comment: Edited the function getHierarchy to be cleaner